# Getting read_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query' error even after passing the query in Python

Tags: python

I have this set in queries.

```
select_queries = {
    'select_mics_for_year': '''
          select distinct eh.segment_mic_code 
               from market_data.exchange_holiday eh 
               where date_part('year',eh.holiday_date) = {}
               and eh.is_substituted = false;
     '''}
```

I have this class where I am calling this query

```
def getTreasurySharesReport():
    print('getTreasury')
    #db_base.read_data(treasuryShares['get_treasury_shares'])

    db_base.DBInteraction.read_data(select_queries ['select_mics_for_year'],chunk_size=10000000, auto_close_connection=False)
    for row in treasuryShares:
        print(row[0])



getTreasurySharesReport()
```

I am getting the following error.
db_base.DBInteraction.read_data(query,chunk_size=10000000, auto_close_connection=False)
TypeError: read_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'

I have passed the query but still getting the error.

Comment: What is `db_base.DBInteraction.read_data`? As long as it is not a `static method`, you have to initialise  a `db_base`-object (or a `db_base.DBInteraction`-object) with `db = db_base()` before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to pass the argument to the query, here:
...
date_part('year',eh.holiday_date) = **{}**

like:
db_base.DBInteraction.read_data(select_queries ['select_mics_for_year'].*format*(***<< Your input argument>>***),chunk_size=10000000, auto_close_connection=False)